# Как поймать сообщение бота telegram api

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, requests, webhook

Я отправляю get запрос на апи телеграмма с параметрами chat_id и massage_text
Бот присылает сообщение в чат
К примеру текст этого сообщения arg1/arg2/arg3
Есть какая-то возможность поймать это же сообщение этим же ботом и получить этот текст(arg1/arg2/arg3) и уже дальше его обрабатывать?
Если есть то буду очень благодарен, поскольку не очень хочется писать апи и поднимать сервер который будет обрабатывать первичный запрос а после уже выполнять основные функции.
Бот будет стоять на вебхуке
За криво составленный вопрос не ругайте, это первый

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.